# Shopping Bot using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am building a bot using selenium which will make purchase from following site:
**[https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051"](https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051%22)**
When I try to login using my credentials using bot, it redirects to page which show login unsuccessful, please try again. Even though that when same credentials are used manually, it show no error.
following is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Fiverr\Practice\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ageVerify']/div[3]/div[1]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ltkpopup-close").click()
driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051")

email=driver.find_element_by_name("logonId")
email.send_keys("mccallister81@gmail.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
password=driver.find_element_by_name("logonPassword")
password.send_keys("Envision1")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
```

Comment: Hey uhhh you might not want to post your password publicly on the internet like that. I'd recommend changing any accounts you use that password for immediately and never using it again

Comment: hi thanks for concern but this email and password is for test purpose.

Comment: It appears that the browser is using some kind of mechanism to check bot-like activity at the login page..

Comment: any idea how to avoid it.